# How to copy symbolic links with relative path in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, symbolic-link, cp

I have this folder `/full/path/sourceFolder` with the following files:

`full/path/sourceFolder/fileA
/full/path/sourceFolder/copyA -> fileA
/full/path/sourceFolder/copyB`

You can see that the symlink point to the file in the same folder and doesn't use full-path but relies on relative path to link.

Now, I need a copy command that would copy all files named copy* in the sourceFolder to a destinationFolder. When I copy file copyA, it should copy the source of symlink i.e. fileA but keep the name copyA. The copy command should also work for copying file copyB.

Can this be done?

I tried these commands but it doesn't work, mostly because my reference is relative:

`cp -rf --preserve=links /full/path/sourceFolder/copy* /target/path/
cp -RP /full/path/sourceFolder/copy* /target/path/
cp -Hrf /full/path/sourceFolder/copy* /target/path/
cp -Lrf /full/path/sourceFolder/copy* /target/path/`

I'm running out of ideas, What is the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you correct your example? Sometimes you include `sourceFolder`, sometimes not. And also show what result you want? `cp path1/* path2/` results in symlinks in path1 being copied to regular files in path2, for me.

Comment: Using 4 spaces at the beginning of the lines is easier for blocks of coding than using lots of ` characters.

Comment: This seems an odd thing to want to do. I would expect a requirement that a copy creates a broken link, which is then resolved when the target is copied. If you want this sort of behaviour, use hard links.

Comment: fixed the paths...

Comment: I cannot recreate the issue. For me the plain `cp /full/path/sourceFolder/copy* /target/path/` works, unless I misunderstood something. The resulting files are regular files with names `copyA` and `copyB`. My testbed is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: @kamil You beat me to it. Seems to be the default `cp` behavior

Answer (score 0):

Following will copy the source file with symlink but failed to copy the referenced file.

```
cp -d /full/path/sourceFolder/copy* /target/path/
```

Following will copy the referenced file also

```
cp -d /full/path/sourceFolder/file* /target/path/
```

> *-d option is a shortcut to –no-dereference –preserve=links*